# simple derivative question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

What is the derivative of $x''(t) = \cos(tx(t))$ with respect to $x'(t)$? I am at a loss at what to do for this simple stated problem. I am not exactly sure what it means to take the derivative with respect to the derivative...

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: There's no explicit occurrence of $x'(t)$. So you can use chain rule and then leave $dx/dv$ along.

Comment: What is $v$? Can you leave an example?

Comment: $v=x'(t)$. I mean, if $x'$ depends on $x$.

Comment: Do you mean that the answer would be $t\sin(tx)\dfrac{dx}{dx'}$

Comment: Also depend on $t$. So almost like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d(x^{''}(t))}{d(x^{'}(t))}=\frac{d\cos(tx(t))}{dx^{'}(t)}=\frac{d\cos(tx(t))}{d(tx(t))}\frac{d(tx(t))}{dx^{'}(t)}=\boxed{-\sin(tx(t))\left(t\frac{dx(t)}{dx^{'}(t)}+x(t)\frac{dt}{dx^{'}(t)}\right)}$$